# Plot angle arches, or how to have a custom `range` for successive (re)plot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to create a 3d plot of some vectors in a unit sphere with angle arches between some of them.
Here is the [current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3W2v.png). <sup>Note: I currently tried only two angle arches but in the end I need some more.</sup>

In order to add the arches, I oriented myself on the following tutorial (near the end '3D Case'): http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/circle/

The problem is, they use `urange` and `vrange` to limit the angle of the arch. They can do this, because they only have two angles in the example and not multiple as I have.

So with my limited mathematical and gnuplot knowledge, I tinkered something together which kind of works:
[my angle arches attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quYQe.png)

What is kind of ungly is, that the line from the 'end' of my angle arch to `0,0,0`is drawn and that even on top of my arrows specified underneath.

Is there a way to plot every arch with different `urange`and `vrange`? Something like:

```
splot cos(u)*cos(v),cos(u)*sin(v),sin(u) notitle lc rgb "#B0000000" linetype 2,\
    [-pi/2:pi/2][0:2*pi] fvx(v),fvy(v),fvz lc rgb "#7878ff" linetype 1,\
    [-pi/2:0][0:2*pi] fux(u),fuy(u),fuz(u)
```

Or is there something I'm completely missing?

Here is my code so far..:

```
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set zrange [-1:1]

set xyplane at 0 #z axis 0 should be on xy-plane


set parametric

set urange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]

set key off

#view schraeg: 32,320
set view 32,320, 1,1
set style arrow 1 linecolor rgb "#FF0000"
set style arrow 2 linecolor rgb "#ff5252" 
set style arrow 3 linecolor rgb "#0000FF" 
set style arrow 4 linecolor rgb "#0000FF" nohead
set style arrow 6 linecolor rgb "#880000FF" nohead
set style arrow 5 linecolor rgb "#FF0000" nohead

# Angle between m' and x axis
r0 = 0.1
fvx(v) = v<2.5793017540894563 ? r0*cos(v) : 0
fvy(v) = v<2.5793017540894563 ? r0*sin(v) : 0
fvz = 0

# Angle between n and m
r = 0.5
fux(u) = u >= 0.7915660086835659 ? r*cos(u)*cos(2.5793017540894563) : 0
fuy(u) = u >= 0.7915660086835659 ? r*cos(u)*sin(2.5793017540894563) : 0
fuz(u) = u >= 0.7915660086835659 ? r*sin(u) : 0

splot cos(u)*cos(v),cos(u)*sin(v),sin(u) notitle lc rgb "#B0000000" linetype 2,\
    fvx(v),fvy(v),fvz lc rgb "#7878ff" linetype 1,\
    fux(u),fuy(u),fuz(u)

set arrow from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 nohead # x axis       
set arrow from 0,0,0 to 0,1.5,0 nohead # y axis
set arrow from 0,0,0 to 0,0,2 nohead # z axis

set arrow from 0,0,0 to 0.49999999999999994, 0, 0.8660254037844387 arrowstyle 1     #light
set arrow from 0,0,0 to 0.49999999999999994, 0, 0 arrowstyle 5      #light 1
set arrow from 0.49999999999999994, 0, 0 to 0.49999999999999994, 0, 0.8660254037844387 arrowstyle 5     #light 2
set arrow from 0,0,0 to -0.49999999999999994, 0, 0.8660254037844387 arrowstyle 2        #specular
set arrow from 0,0,0 to -0.6078313957973345, 0.3830222215594889, 0.6955824696430309 arrowstyle 3        #measure
set arrow from 0,0,0 to -0.6078313957973345, 0.3830222215594889, 0 arrowstyle 6                         #measure flat
set arrow from 0,0.3830222215594889,0 to -0.6078313957973345, 0.3830222215594889, 0 arrowstyle 6        #measure 1
set arrow from -0.6078313957973345,0,0 to -0.6078313957973345, 0.3830222215594889, 0 arrowstyle 6       #measure 2
set arrow from -0.6078313957973345, 0.3830222215594889, 0 to -0.6078313957973345, 0.3830222215594889, 0.6955824696430309 arrowstyle 4       #measure 3


pause -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot specify the range (because you are using a `replot` approach, which is sensible), then, change the function!

You can make a change of variable to accomodate any other range. Say:

```
set parametric
set urange [0:pi]
splot 0,0,0 # because internal variables are not initialised else, this will not be a problem in your example.
CoV(u,min,max)=min+(u-GPVAL_U_MIN)*(max-min)/(GPVAL_U_MAX-GPVAL_U_MIN)
splot cos(CoV(u,pi/3,pi/2)),sin(CoV(u,pi/3,pi/2)),0
```

The CoV (change of variable) uses the ranges of variable `u` at the time of plotting (Gnuplot variables `GPVAL_U_*`) to rescale `u` between the prescribed minimum and maximum values. The ugly `splot 0,0,0` might be spared with future versions of gnuplot using `stats` command, but not yet with version 5.0. Alternatively, one can set his own variables initially:

```
my_u_min=0.
my_u_max=pi
set urange [my_u_min:my_u_max]
U_MIN(dummy)=(exists("GPVAL_U_MIN")?GPVAL_U_MIN:my_u_min)
U_MAX(dummy)=(exists("GPVAL_U_MAX")?GPVAL_U_MAX:my_u_max)
CoV(u,min,max)=min+(u-U_MIN(0))*(max-min)/(U_MAX(0)-U_MIN(0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm, though I don't understand th `CoV` function right now, but I'll dig a bit into the documentation on those variables.

Comment: I've added some comments.